# Excel Plotting two Date Ranges on the same Pivot Table

Tags: excel, date, charts, pivot

I am trying to trend the occurrence of a system event in Excel. I've attached a screen shot showing the pretty simple data that I'm working with.

The spreadsheet lists the times of the event (Column A) for a two week period and I've used a ceiling formula to group those events into 15 minute increments (Column B).  Using a pivot table and chart, it's pretty simple to then take that data and graph the events into a line chart that shows the 15 minute increment time, and the count of the events in that 15 minute period.

Now I'd like to take subsets of that data and compare them. For example I'd like to compare Friday Saturday Sunday of last week Friday Saturday and Sunday of this week.  So far, the only way I found to achieve this is to create duplicate pivot tables (Columns E, F and H,I), filter each table by the days I want to compare (25, 26, and 27 in one table and 1, 2 and 3 in the second), and then visually compare them (the Two charts).

But what I'd really like to do is to combine both series into one chart as a stacked line graph.  I thought that would be pretty simple, but since the dates are so very dissimilar, I always wind up getting a single line or duplicate data, or totally off the wall results.

I've gotten kinda close by converting the row labels in to a custom DDD HH:MM format.  That lists the Dates as (For Oct 25th)

- Fri 00:15   11
- Fri 00:30   1
- Fri 00:45   4
- Fri 01:00   3
- Fri 01:15   6
- Etc.

And (For Nov 1st)

- Fri 00:15   7
- Fri 00:30   1
- Fri 00:45   2
- Fri 01:00   1
- Fri 01:30   2
- Etc

Now I have something I can join on (Friday 00:15, 00:30, 00:45, etc is in both charts)

But the problem is, the two series often don't have the same Labels.  For example the data for Nov 1 is missing 01:15,01:45 and 02:00 because no events occurred at those times.  Same problem for the Oct 25th's data which is also missing 02:00 in addition to all increments between 02:30 and 03:45.

I tried just manually inserting the missing times in both charts but that quickly became a very complex and error prone chore.

So the question is: Is there a way to get excel to automatically fill in the missing time slots or am I completely off base in the way I'm trying to do this?

OK.. that was two questions  :)

Thanks so much for your help!

[image: Excel Sheet Showing Raw Data, Pivot Tables, and Charts]

Comment: do you have access to power pivot?

Comment: Hi Terry.  No not currently. I'm afraid we're stuck with 2010 until we get the O365 licensing working out next year.  Although I now that I think about it... maybe.

If I could get access, what are you thinking?

Comment: OK  I DO have access to Power Piviot now